# Python Pandas groupby multiple columns and append

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm close to achieve what I want thanks to [Python Pandas Groupby/Append columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788177/python-pandas-groupby-append-columns) but still not quite there.

**DF:**

| City | Plan | Problem 1 | Problem 2 | Problem 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Genoa | Service 1 | aaa | bbb | ccc |
| Genoa | Service 2 | ddd | zzz | yyy |
| Genoa | Service 3 | ggg | ppp | jjj |
| Venice | Service 2 | lll | vvv |  |
| Venice | Service 3 | eee | fff | mmm |

**Expected Output:**

| City | Problem 1 | Problem 2 | Problem 3 | Problem 4 | Problem 5 | Problem 6 | Problem 7 | Problem 8 | Problem 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Genoa | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd | zzz | yyy | ggg | ppp | jjj |
| Venice |  |  |  | lll | vvv |  | eee | fff | mmm |

Basically I want to:

1. Group by City
2. Discard Plan Column (if possible)
3. Append all the other parameters (They still need to be always in order, so if a service is missing the cells would be empty.

After playing a while with unstack and cumcount from the linked solution, I'm still missing something to respect the order of the Plan column and fill with empty cells if a service is missing.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

df1 = df.set_index('City').stack().reset_index(name='vals')
df1['g'] = 'Param' + df1.groupby('City').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df1 = df1.pivot(index='City', columns='g', values='vals')

df1.to_csv('output.csv')
```

In my tests I've removed the **Plan** column from the input, but the problem is that after ordering the parameters in the output, if, for example, a city has only **Service 3**, they are still aligned under **Service 1**.

Comment: Could you please add an executable code sample which is also showing where you are stuck?

Comment: Got it, just added an example I'm using for test, although I can't figure out how to modify it to consider the Plan column too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pivot problem, but you can also do this by stacking and unstacking:

```
s = df.set_index(['City', 'Plan']).stack().unstack([1, 2])
s.columns = 'Problem ' + pd.RangeIndex(1, s.shape[1]+1).astype(str)

print (s)

       Problem 1 Problem 2 Problem 3 Problem 4 Problem 5 Problem 6 Problem 7 Problem 8 Problem 9
City                                                                                            
Genoa        aaa       bbb       ccc       ddd       zzz       yyy       ggg       ppp       jjj
Venice       NaN       NaN       NaN       lll       vvv       NaN       eee       fff       mmm
```

---

Another way using `melt`:

```
s = df.melt(['City', 'Plan']).pivot('City', ['Plan', 'variable'], 'value')
s.columns = 'Problem ' + pd.RangeIndex(1, s.shape[1]+1).astype(str)

print (s)
       Problem 1 Problem 2 Problem 3 Problem 4 Problem 5 Problem 6 Problem 7 Problem 8 Problem 9
City                                                                                            
Genoa        aaa       ddd       ggg       bbb       zzz       ppp       ccc       yyy       jjj
Venice       NaN       lll       eee       NaN       vvv       fff       NaN       NaN       mmm
```

The ordering is a bit different, but the relative ordering between Services is preserved.

Comment: really like the first solution, nice to see your around

Comment: @Manakin Hello! Not sure we've met or if I knew you from before as a different username, sorry. Good to see you!

Comment: @cs95 this this the trick, thank you, and easy to understand. Still trying getting around Pandas potential.

Comment: my old nick was Datanovice, i was forced to change as I've been told I'm no longer a novice ;) @cs95

Comment: @Manakin Ah that rings a bell, I remember you used to comment on some of my older answers with follow up questions (which, of course, I was happy to oblige most of the time ;- )